# How to get all pending tasks of an event loop in Python/FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, event-loop, starlette

I am trying to understand potential slowdown in my FastAPI app.

My understanding is that each time I do an `await`, a task is scheduled for later, creating a backlog of task to be executed. If the process is slow for some reason, the number of pending tasks should raise. How can I monitor the number of pending tasks?

Answer (score 3):

You could do that using [`asyncio.all_tasks(loop=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.all_tasks):

> Returns a set of not yet finished [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) objects run by the loop.
>
> If *loop* is None, [`get_running_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop) is used for getting current
> loop.

As described in [this article](https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-all-tasks/) (which I would suggest having a look at):

> ##### How to Get All Asyncio Tasks
>
> We may need to get access to all tasks in an asyncio program.
>
> This may be **for many reasons**, such as:
>
> - To introspect the current status or complexity of the program.
> - To log    the details of all running tasks.
> - To find a task that can be queried    or canceled.
>
> We can get **a set of all scheduled and running (not yet done) tasks** in
> an asyncio program via the `asyncio.all_tasks()` function.
>
> For example:
>
> ```py
> # get all tasks 
> tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
> ```
>
> This will return a set of all tasks in the asyncio program.
>
> It is a set so that each task is only represented once.
>
> A task **will be included if**:
>
> - The task has been scheduled but is not yet running.
> - The task is currently running (e.g., but is currently suspended)
>
> The set **will also include a task for the currently running task**, e.g.,
> the task that is executing the coroutine that calls the
> `asyncio.all_tasks()` function.
>
> Also, recall that the `asyncio.run()` method that is used to start an
> asyncio program will wrap the provided coroutine in a task. This means
> that the set of all tasks **will also include the task for the entry point of the program**.

Moreover, as explained in this [related article](https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-stuck-long-running-tasks/), one could **monitor** and get details about all running tasks, in order to **detect any stuck long-running tasks** in the `asyncio` event loop, as follows:

```py
...
# get all tasks
for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
    # log the task
    logging.debug(task)
```

which would return something like:

```
DEBUG:root:<Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<work() running at /...> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]> cb=[TaskGroup._on_task_done()]>
```

Further, one could report the full stack trace of each task:

```py
...
# get all tasks
for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
    # report the trace
    task.print_stack()
```

Finally, your understanding about `async`/`await` (coroutines) in asynchronous programming is not entirely correct, and thus, I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details.